# TCP socket server with consumer-producer design 'cpu time limit exceeded'

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, concurrency, producer-consumer

this problem came up while running a socket server created using consumer/producer design, the program crashed with error `cpu time limit exceeded` in log. also i found that `cpu` usage was more than `90%` at the time. here's the code of the server, what could be gone wrong with it and how can i optimize this ?

i used this `queue` approach to avoid creation of so many `threads` for each request.

**in main method (main thread)**

```
//holds socket instances
ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Socket> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

//create producer thread
Thread producer = new Thread(new RequestProducer(queue));
//create consumer thread
Thread consumer = new Thread(new RequestConsumer(queue));

producer.start();
consumer.start();
```

**RequestProducer thread**

```
//this holds queue instance coming from main thread
ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Socket> queue

//constructor, initiate queue
public RequestProducer(
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Socket> queue
) {
    this.queue = queue;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        //create serversocket instance on port 19029
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(19029);
        while (true) {
            try {
                //keep accept connections
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                //add socket to queue
                queue.offer(socket);
            } catch (ConnectException ce) {//handle exception
            } catch (SocketException e) {//handle exception
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {//handle exception}
}
```

**RequestConsumer thread**

```
//this holds queue instance coming from main thread, same as requestproducer
ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Socket> queue

//constructor, initiate queue
public RequestConsumer(
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Socket> queue
) {
    this.queue = queue;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        Socket socket = null;
        while (true) {
            //get head of the queue (socket instance)
            socket = queue.poll();
            if (null != socket) {
                //process data stream
                String in = DataStreamUtil.parseAsciiSockStream(socket.getInputStream());
                //close socket conection
                socket.close();
                //excecute database insert of processed data
                excecuteDbInsert(in);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException | ParseException ex) {//handle exceptions}
}
```

**Data stream parser**

```
public static String parseAsciiSockStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    if (null != in) {
        byte[] b = new byte[BYTE_STREAM_MAX];
        int length = in.read(b);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            builder.append((char) (int) b[i]);
        }
        in.close();
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Java programs do not 'crash with error cpu time limit exceeded'. That's a PHP error message. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: i started this program by `java -jar GpsServer.jar >/var/log/gps-server-log.log 2>&1` command, few minutes later i saw this server is stuck and last line of this log file is `cpu time limit exceeded`. Also i wrote `upstart conf` file to start server as a service.

Comment: @EJP It's definitely NOT a PHP error message and CAN happen with Java too. It's Signal 24 (SIGXCPU) in Linux.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CPU time limit exceeded due to aggressive `while(true)` loop into your Consumer. below is an example how you can solve the problem.

You can add simple `Thread.sleep(1)` in your while loop into the Consumer or use wait/notify pattern to limit CPU consumption.

**RequestProducer thread**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ConnectException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;

public class RequestProducer implements Runnable {
    //this holds queue instance coming from main thread
    final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Socket> queue;

    //constructor, initiate queue
    public RequestProducer(
            ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Socket> queue
    ) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            //create serversocket instance on port 19029
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(19029);
            while (true) {
                try {
                    //keep accept connections
                    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    //add socket to queue
                    queue.offer(socket);
                    synchronized (queue) {
                        System.out.println("notifying");
                        queue.notify();
                    }
                } catch (ConnectException ce) {//handle exception
                } catch (SocketException e) {//handle exception
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {//handle exception}
        }

    }
}
```

**RequestConsumer thread**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;

public class RequestConsumer implements Runnable {
    //this holds queue instance coming from main thread, same as requestproducer
    final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Socket> queue;

    //constructor, initiate queue
    public RequestConsumer(
            ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Socket> queue
    ) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Socket socket = null;
            while (true) {
                //get head of the queue (socket instance)
                System.out.println("Waiting for new socket");
                synchronized (queue) {
                    queue.wait();
                }
                System.out.println("Acquired new socket");

                socket = queue.poll();
                try {
                    if (null != socket) {
                        //process data stream
                        String in = DataStreamUtil.parseAsciiSockStream(socket.getInputStream());
                        //close socket conection
                        socket.close();
                        //excecute database insert of processed data
                        //excecuteDbInsert(in);

                        System.out.println(in);
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (socket != null) {
                        socket.close();
                    }
                }

            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {//handle exceptions}
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

}
```

**Data stream parser**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class DataStreamUtil {
    public static String parseAsciiSockStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        if (null != in) {
            byte[] b = new byte[BYTE_STREAM_MAX];
            System.out.println("Waiting for input");
            int length = in.read(b);
            System.out.println("Got input");
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                builder.append((char) (int) b[i]);
            }
            in.close();
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```